# How can I change the id of every div with a table which has n number of id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table like this:

```
<tr id="Article1">
    <td id="CheckboxDiv1">
        <div class="checkbox" style="text-align:center">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="CheckboxArticle1" onchange="OnChange(this);">
            </label>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td id="Metal1">gold</td>
    <td id="Description1">Ring</td>
    <td id="Quantity1">2</td>
    <td id="Weight1">90</td>
    <td id="Purity1">100</td><td id="PureWeight1">1</td>
    <td id="Remarks1">bend</td>

</tr>

<tr id="Article2">
    <td id="CheckboxDiv2">
        <div class="checkbox" style="text-align:center">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="CheckboxArticle2" onchange="OnChange(this);">
            </label>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td id="Metal2">gold</td>
    <td id="Description2">Ring</td>
    <td id="Quantity2">2</td>
    <td id="Weight2">90</td>
    <td id="Purity2">100</td><td id="PureWeight1">1</td>
    <td id="Remarks2">bend</td>

</tr>
```

I Tried The Following Code To Get The id

```
var RowCount=2;
for(i=1;i<=RowCount;i++)
{
    ColoumnId[i]=$("#Article"+i+" > td").map(function (){
            return this.id;
        }).get();
}
```

I get the Id of all the column but I also need to get the Id of the "CheckBox" which is "CheckboxArticle1","CheckboxArticle2". Can someone please suggest me how to get the Id. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not see a `div` with an ID - which ID do you want change?

Comment: To change an element id you need a reference to that element, but if you already have a reference what is the point of changing the id? **What is the underlying problem that you're trying to solve by changing the IDs?**

Answer (score 0):

Since you work with jQuery this line of code should work:

```
$('form#idOfYourForm tr').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('id') //your id for every tr
})
```

And with this way you can get your other IDs as well.

Comment: Or you give each of your `tr`s a class called `article` and select them with `$('.article')` - there are many ways to reach your goal.

Answer (score 0):

This should work using JQuery:

```
$("[id^='Article'] input[type=checkbox]").each(function(i, item) {
    alert($(item).attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the id's of the input fields, try this

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each ( function (index,entry) {  console.log ( $(this).attr('id') ) })
```